# Same website different port Javascript and Stylesheets

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-membership, port

I've a website running under IIS7. Everything works fine with this website. I've copied the directory and created a clone website on a different port. When I browse to the new website on the different port, I do not get any of the style settings until I log in -- then all appears normally.

**The problem appears to do with the ASP.NET Membership/Authorization. I have a web.config in the subdirectories to allow all users (web.config) but the clone website is not using them even though all the config, directories, etc are the same. Only the port is different or non .config settings that IIS 7 uses.**

---

I've discovered the problem but not the whole answer. The directories needed the IUSR permission to work but the original website doesn't have those permissions. It only had IIS_IUSRS. IF anyone can fully explain this behavior and how to fix the problem without granting IUSR then I will award the bounty for that answer.

The answer should be fully explanatory.

Comment: Take a look at the http requests and see if they are being done, also check the http response and see what it says (specially if the asking for the right file through the right port).

Comment: If you want to add the bounty, feel free to bring up another one, but since the details you added kind of change the context for the existing answer, I had to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue would be with authorization settings in your config.

Look for something like this:

```
  <location path="MyResourcesFolder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The above example would produce the effect that you've described assuming that your resources (css, jscript, etc) were located in a folder named *MyResourcesFolder*.  Check the web.config that's in the actual website and not necessarily the project.  This is because your website config may not be the same as your project config if you are using config transformations.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be a problem. I've just copied everything. Its an identical copy. Nothing has changed. It is for sure a membership configuration issue but not sure how or why

Comment: But its not nested.. I just took the root folder, copied it, and created a new website for it. It seems I can't get to any of the resources I've allowed unless I logged in.

Comment: That's odd.  Are the IIS authentication settings the exact same?  Seems like it would be an IIS issue.

Comment: They are exactly the same. Shouldn't all IIS settings be the same since I copied the directory? It just uses the web.config files right? Well there are bindings. It must be something not stored in the web.config but that I need to do in the editor. Not sure what though

Comment: I do believe the config files override some of the IIS settings.  And you say the config files are identical?

Comment: Everything is identical. I copied the entire site directory. its just a carbon copy